# How do I read this text file into the following class array?

Tags: java

I have a class Student and two children classes, CasualStudent and PermanentStudent. I am doing this right now.

```
Employee[] a = new Employee[10];
int count;
a[0] = new PermanentStudent("John", "LUI", "HJFDDFDFJ"); 
a[1] = new PermanentStudent("Peter", "VAMPLEW", "VAM12345678");
a[2] = new PermanentStudent("Rudi", "SKACEL", "SKA51515151");
a[3] = new CasualStudent("Katie","BLACKBURN","BLA41925612");
a[4] = new CasualStudent("Neal","STEPHENSON","STE97527467");
a[5] = new CasualStudent("Neneh","CHERRY","CHE98765432");
a[6] = new CasualStudent("Chris","BROOKMYRE","BRO97635198");
a[7] = new CasualStudent("Grace","HOPPER","HOP26554432");
a[8] = new CasualStudent("Randall","MUNROE","XKCD1234567");
a[9] = new CasualStudent("Kaylee","FRYE","FRY90224718");
```

Each of these children classes have a constructor and I have manually coded the data in the code. Now, I want to read this data from a .txt file. I know how to read and I have done this till now:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
        "file.txt"));
    while (true) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
        break;
        }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    }
}
```

But how do I read the data into the classes like this? I am new to Java and I am not able to understand how to do this? Please guide me in the right direction. Thanks!

Also, the text file will always contain 10 lines and each line will have the following format.

```
John LUI HJFDDFDFJ
..................
```

Code:

```
61. int i = 0;
62. for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
63. {
64.     String x = a[i].toString();
65.     System.out.println(x);
66. }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way would be as follows:

```
Employee[] employees = new Employee[10];
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))) {

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
    employees[i] = new PermanentStudent(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2])
  }

  for (int i = 3; i < 10; i++) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
    employees[i] = new CasualStudent(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2])
  }
}
```

Comment: Both of these are children classes of the base class Student. How do I do it then?

Comment: I mean, how can you decide that based on the data in your text file?

Comment: Oh! So the first three entries in the file will be for PermanentStudent and the other 7 will be for CasualStudent.  Also, the code that you have written, does it go inside the while (true) loop?

Comment: I have expanded my answer

Comment: it shows the following error when the file is being executed. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at StudentSystem.main(StudentSystem.java:64)`. My file.txt contains 10 lines and each line has same data (set it as same in order to test).

Comment: I have updated my original post with line numbers. The lines 61-64 basically print the contents of array `a` which is same as your `student` array.

Comment: @HarryLewis seems that you better posting new question with the full code :)

Comment: I feel it's just a small error of string Conversion. It will be great if you can just see my update in the question.

Comment: it's done. Your second for loop should begin from 3 instead of 6 and that was the error.